# A confidence area for an Archimedean's copula family

Tags: self-study, distributions, confidence-interval, random-variable, copula

I'm reading the paper by [Lourme A. et al (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.econmod.2016.12.014) and tried to plot $2D$ confidence areas like on the Fig.2. Discussion about confidence areas of normal distributed data and some results are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310989/how-to-draw-an-alpha-confidence-areas-on-a-2d-plot).

Let's remind the definition of confidence areas from the paper:

> 4.1.2. Confidence areas
>
> Let $u = (u_1,…,u_d)′$ be a random vector with uniform margins on $(0,1)$ and let $y = (y_1,…, y_d)′ \in \mathbb{R}$ be defined by: $y_j =
> G(u_j), ( j \in {1,…,d})$ where $G$ is a continuous increasing map
>   defined between $0$ and $1$.
>
> Let us assume that the multivariate c.d.f of
>   $u$ is a Gaussian copula with parameter $R_g$. Taking the quantile
>   function of $\mathcal{N_1}(0, 1)$ as $G$, then $y$ is distributed as
>   $\mathcal{N_d}(0, R_g)$ and the random variable $y′R_g^{−1} y$ as
>   $χ^2_d$. Given $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, the latter variable $y′R_g^{−1} y$
>   is less than $χ_{d,α}^2$ – the $\alpha$ order quantile of $χ^2_d$ –
>   with probability $\alpha$. Hence,
>   $$\Gamma_g(\alpha)=\{\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots, \nu_d)' \in [0, 1]^d;
> \\(G(\nu_1), \ldots,G(\nu_d)) R_g^{-1}(G(\nu_1), \ldots,G(\nu_d))' \le
> \chi^2_{d,\alpha}\}$$ is a $d$-dimensional compact confidence area
>   inside (resp. outside) of which $u$ falls with probability $\alpha$
>   (resp. $1 − \alpha$).

Also in the paper one  can find the formula of $d$-dimensional compact confidence area for Student's t distributed data:

> $$\Gamma_t(\alpha)=\{\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots, \nu_d)' \in [0, 1]^d;
> \\(G(\nu_1), \ldots,G(\nu_d)) R_t^{-1}(G(\nu_1), \ldots,G(\nu_d))' \le
> d \times \mathcal{F}_{d, v, \alpha}\}$$

where  $\mathcal{F}_{d, v, \alpha}$ – the $\alpha$ order quantile of the Fisher distribution $\mathcal{F}_{d, \nu}$ – with probability $\alpha$, and $d$ and $v$ degrees of freedom.

Trus, the $d$-dimensional compact confidence area is defind for the elliptical case (Normal and Student's $t$).

**Question.** Could someone explain a used approach in order to derive a confidence area formula to multivariate distibuted data that approximated with an Archimedean copula? for instance, a [Frank's copula](http://www.assetinsights.net/Glossary/G_Frank_Copula.html) or a [Gumbel](http://www.assetinsights.net/Glossary/G_Gumbel_Copula.html) one.

**Edit 2.**

Lets $\Psi_\infty$ is the class of completely monotone generators $\psi$, i.e., $(−1)^k\psi^{(k)}(t) \ge 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. 
By Bernstein’s Theorem, the class of completely monotone generators precisely coincides with the class of Laplace–Stieltjes transforms ($\mathcal{LS}$) of distribution functions $F$ on the positive real line, that is, any completely
monotone generator allows for the representation [Grothe et al (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X14002693)
$$\psi(t) = \mathcal{LS}[F](t) = \int^{\infty}_0 exp(−tx) dF(x).$$
This representation has an important consequence for sampling
since it provides a stochastic representation for $U \sim C$. In the paper by [Hofert et al (2012)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0047259X12000607/1-s2.0-S0047259X12000607-main.pdf?_tid=f546e9c2-2ae0-11e7-b9bf-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1493253313_1c02f7f2c27a015521b87e90bebcfaf4) one can found

> A random vector $U$ following an Archimedean copula with generator
>   $\psi ∈ \Psi_\infty$ allows for the stochastic representation
>   $U=(\psi(E_1/V),...,\psi (E_d/V))^⊤$, where $V \sim
> F=\mathcal{LS}^{−1}(\psi)$ and i.i.d. $E_j \sim Exp(1)$, $j \in
> \{1,..., d\}$.

$\mathcal{LS}^{−1}(\psi)$ is the inverse of Laplace–Stieltjes transform of a generator $\psi$, for the Clayton copula the parameter $\theta \in (0,\infty)$, the generator $\psi(t)= (1+t)^{−1/\theta}$, and  $ V \sim \Gamma(1/\theta,1)$.

Archimedean families (Ali-Mikhail-Haq, Clayton, Frank, Gumbel, and Joe) with corresponding parameter ranges, generators, and
inverse Laplace-Stieltjes transforms can be found in the paper
[Hofert (2008)](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi/forschung/PreprintServer/2007/preprintmariushofert.pdf).

**Reference.** [Lourme, A., F. Maurer (2016) Testing the Gaussian and Student's t copulas in a risk management framework. Economic Modelling.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.econmod.2016.12.014)

[Marius Hofert, Martin Mächler, Alexander J. McNeil. Likelihood inference for Archimedean copulas in high dimensions under known margins. Journal of Multivariate Analysis 110 (2012) 133–150.](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0047259X12000607/1-s2.0-S0047259X12000607-main.pdf?_tid=f546e9c2-2ae0-11e7-b9bf-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1493253313_1c02f7f2c27a015521b87e90bebcfaf4)

[Marius Hofert (2008) Sampling Archimedean copulas. Part of the Hofert’s dissertation.](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi/forschung/PreprintServer/2007/preprintmariushofert.pdf)

[O. Grothe, M. Hofert, Construction and sampling of Archimedean
and nested Archimedean L´evy copulas, Journal of Multivariate Analysis (2014), http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmva.2014.12.004](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X14002693)